# Sending an HTTP request with client certificates in Chrome

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates, mutual-authentication

I have an API on Azure that is protected with [mutual authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_authentication). The server certificate is internally handled by Azure:

[image: Server Certificate]

I've created a self signed certificate and added it to my local computer's list of *Trusted Root Certification Authorities* as well as my *Personal* certificates:

[image: Client Certificate]

When attempting to hit the API through Chrome (specifically the Chrome App Postman), I'm getting a 403 indicating my request didn't have a certificate associated with it.

1. Do I have a misunderstanding of how this should work?
2. It's possible I've created the client certificate incorrectly. Everything I read online point to using OpenSSL to create these, however I had some issues getting it to run on a Windows machine and went through a variety of other tools: [MakeCert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx), PowerShell's [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848633(v=wps.630).aspx), and [Self-Signed Certificate Generator](http://www.selfsignedcertificate.com/). All seem to create certificates, but I have no real way of knowing if I created them correctly.
3. If the certificate was created correctly, how do I get Chrome to submit the certificate with the request? Shouldn't it just automatically pick up the cert when I add it to the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to go to the root url of the site in chrome (i.e. https://my_app_name.azurewebsites.net) and chrome would display a pop up allowing me to choose the certificate to use with the request.